# How to log out of spotify API authentication flow demo

Tags: node.js, json, spotify

I've been researching the spotify api by following [this guide](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/) and I set up the authentication and installed all the packages. I can log in to my own account by just clicking log in, and I can modify all the things like shown on their developer website. However, I can't find a way to log out my account so that I can try it with other accounts. As far as I know, you don't change the client ID, Secret, or URI. Since this is on the local server, I can't ask someone else to log in on a different device. Things I have tried:

Looking on the local host server for a log out button

Searching through app.js for somewhere to change the use

Stopping the server and turning it on again

Changing the client secret

Answer (score 1):

If you send the user to `accounts.spotify.com/logout`, they will be logged out. Bear in mind that this logs them out of spotify.com, including the web player.

To log a user out of Spotify within your application, you should delete their access token. That way your app can't contact Spotify again.

If you want to have a user log in with a different account, send them to the same url you send them to for login, but add a query parameter `show_dialog=true`. This way, the user can click the "not you?" button and log into another account before authorizing your application.